# Asp.net mvc 4 razor How keep types in my Controller when saving a list in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, type-conversion, covariance

I have a big problem and I'm a little bit disappointed.  I can't find a good solution with this problem:

I have `CompanyA` and `CompanyB` who specialize `Company` who has an interface `ICompany`
in my controller.  I then load from different databases, `companyA` and `companyB` in my `List<company>`.  In my `EditorView`, I display the different objects `companyA` and `companyB`.

When I'm saving, in my controller, my objects in my list aren't to type `CompanyA` and `CompanyB`, but they are all of type `Company`.

How can I keep my types when I save?

Here is some code if my explanation is not clear:

My example CompanyViewModel.cs:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    #region Properties
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ExternalAccounts ExtAccounts { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; } // or List<object> Companies { get; set; }
    ....
    #region Ctor
    public CompanyViewModel()
    { }
    public CompanyViewModel(ExternalAccounts extAccount, bool iniPrefLanguage = true)
    {
        //normaly it's load from bdd 
        ...
        Companies = new List<Company>();

        if (test == true)
        {
            Companies.Add(new CompanyA()); // call webService
        }
        if (test2 == true)
        {
            Companies.Add(new CompanyB());

        }
        ...
        #region
}
```

OR I can have:

```
    public ActionResult EditCompanies()
    {
        ...

        // Companies = new List<Company>();
         Model.Companies.Add(new CompanyA()); // call webService
         Model.Companies.Add(new CompanyB());                

        return View(Model);
    }

    public ActionResult SaveCompanies(ComapnyViewModel model)
    {
        var test = model.Companies.OfType<CompanyA>(); // return null !!!
        test = model.Companies.OfType<CompanyB>(); // return null !!!!
        test = model.Companies.OfType<Company>(); // return my objects !!!!

        return View();
    }
```

in view

```
       @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Companies)
```

and i have EditorTemplate with Company.cshtml, CompanyA.cshtml, CompanyB.cshtml

During my load in View, each object in my list go to the right EditorTemplate (CompanyA and CompanyB)

But when i save... I  have a list of company type only ...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Don't do that.  View models should not contain complex data like that.  The model binder cannot work like this.

Comment: SLaks is right, in fact they are called Views because your only concern should be the presentation. Move your logic to the controllers at least.

Comment: Thank you for response but i must edit CompanyA and CompanyB in the same view. I should add this CompanyA and CompanyB in list<company>... In ViewModel or Controller, i have the same problem... My question is how to keep the types (CompanyA and CompanyB) in my list when i saved. Because for display, it's ok. I must mixed CompanyA and CompanyB in the same view... it's not my choice

Comment: But MVC has no way to tell the type when it comes back as elements in a POST. It doesn't work like serialized ViewState. You could maybe implement your own ModelBinder that could do it based on some extra "type" attribute, but I think that may be overkill. ViewModels should be relatively simple, and easily re-recreatable by MVC through default constructors.

Comment: Ok now i have the logic in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is:

I created a view with Company as model, and a partial view with CompanyA as model, and another view with CompanyB as model. Inside CompanyView, I called `Html.Partial("CompanyAView", Model)` and `Html.Partial("CompanyBView", Model)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand... how to do that if you are a list<company>... In my view, i do @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Companies)
and it call the good EditorTemplate companyA.cshtml and companyB.cshtml. is it that ?